# How to pass variable name in hover function of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

want to pass variable name in hover function of javascript

```
     $(".icon a").hover(function() { 
            //
       });
```

I want to use some variable name in place of (.icon a)
        eg

```
        var name=anyvalue;
        $(name).hover(function(){
       //
    });
```

Comment: You mean, get the variable name inside hover function?

Comment: so just use it like you said - `var name= '.icon a';  $(name).hover(function(){ });`

Comment: Yes mate, there is no problem using it like described on your question. Anyway be aware that jQuery will not obey the variable value, eg, if you change the variable name's value it will not affect the jQuery selection..

Comment: Would this work for you:
var name=$(".icon a") or any jQuery element;
name.hover(function(){ });

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, or you can assign the object itself to a variable. Like so

```
var iconName = ".icon a";
$(iconName).hover(function(){ });
```

or

```
var $icon = $(".icon a");
$icon.hover(function () { });
```

or even both

```
var iconName = ".icon a";
var $icon = $(iconName);
$icon.hover(function () { });
```

Comment: <script>
$j(document).on('mouseover', 'input', function() {
    var image_id=$j(this).attr('id');
 var quotee="'";
 var hashe="#";
 var dotte=".";
 var image_path=quotee+hashe+image_id+quotee;
 var image_class=dotte+image_id;
 
 var final_path=quotee+image_class+quotee;
  //alert(image_path);
 $j(image_path).hover(
    // show
    function(){
  $j('.blouse-dummy-img').hide();
        $j(final_path).show();
    },
 
    // hide
    function() {
        $j(final_path).hide();
  $j('.blouse-dummy-img').show(); 
});
});
</script>

Comment: I have this code and want to get id of input type and hover this id using javascript and onhover show class which has same value as Id fetched